# SQL Grouping and dense rank concept

Tags: sql

I have a data set that looks like:

```
 cust   city    hotel_id amount
 -------------------------------
   A    1        252    3160
   B    1        256    1893
   C    2        105    2188
   D    2        105    3054
   E    3        370    6107
   F    2        110    3160
   G    2        150    1893
   H    3        310    2188
   I    1        252    3160
   J    1        250    4000
   K    3        370    5000 
   L    3        311    1095
```

Query to display the top 3 hotels by revenue (Sum of amount) for each city?
Since same hotel can be booked by other customer in same city so we need to sum the amount to find total amount.

Expected output:

```
city    hotel_id    amount
---------------------------
  1       252        6320
  1       250        4000
  1       256        1893

  2       105        5242
  2       110        3160
  2       150        1893

  3       370       11107
  3       310        2188
  3       311        1095
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    t.city, t.hotel_id, t.amount
FROM
(
    SELECT city, hotel_id, SUM(amount) AS amount,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY city ORDER BY SUM(amount) DESC) AS rn
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY city, hotel_id
) t
WHERE t.rn <= 3
ORDER BY t.city, t.amount DESC;
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: PARTITON BY hotel_id, but we need to Partition by city and hotel id and in sum the amount to find maximum amount earned

Comment: Thanks. I added one more row ( for tie) and used dense rank.. You can check.

Answer (score 0):

To get the total sum for each hotel_id you need to group by that column first, then group by the city for syntax purposes. The #tmp table here should have all of the data you need, so then you just have to select the top 3 entries for each city from there.

```
SELECT city, hotel_id, SUM(amount) AS 'total' INTO #tmp
FROM [table]
GROUP BY hotel_id, city

(SELECT TOP 3 *
FROM #tmp
WHERE city = 1)
UNION
(SELECT TOP 3 *
FROM #tmp
WHERE city = 2)
UNION
(SELECT TOP 3 *
FROM #tmp
WHERE city = 3)
```

Comment: will it work when we have same sum value for different hotel in same city..?